# Video365 - Is it possible to create an audit on Video365 stats to get userrelated information?

Tags: office365

Edited question:

Hey there,

while introducing this Office365 feature for a customer the works council related question comes up if it is possible to create an audit on videos in the Video365 hub to get statistics of single user.
This is somewhat crucial as it is forbidden to track such information or at least ensure that no normal user is able to get such information to use it against others.
It wouldn't be a problem if an administrator is able to do so as it is with several other technologies, but it must be restricted to that at most.

I searched for at least a week with google and digged through several forums (Stackexchange, DevNet, TechNet, ...) and blogs etc., but without success.
I started some topics in such forums, but also to no avail.
I understand as this is a rather new technology and it will also change over the course of time, maybe disappear, maybe it will evolve and more will be possible.  But we need to give the customer an answer.

So does anyone have some experience with that?

Cheers, Happy

(I hope it is better described as it was before.)

Comment: Downvoting without telling why? For what reason?

Comment: I would guess the reason for the downvotes would be that you don't appear to have researched or tried anything yet, or if you have you haven't noted what you've learned or tried. Questions that show a little self-work tend to be better received that those that only ask a question without demonstrating the steps OP may have already tried.

Comment: Another issue may be that this is that Video365 is probably a WebApp mostly, and there is a WebApps SE site where you may find more knowledgeable people on this particular topic.

Comment: I wouldn't have asked here if my own research on this topic would have brought me some answers.
I found nothing regarding this topic which told me anything in this matter, neither positive nor negative, so I would have only been able to tell you that I've found nothing for that and decided to not write it down.
That's why I asked here. I apoligize for that I was not aware of the necessity of writing a novell for such a simple question (I orientated myself on other topics which are most of the time quite short and also without more information without downvotes).

Comment: Eh, don't worry. The downvote squads come and go. We're mostly not a bad sort, but we've got our share of spoiled apples. I've been victim of downvote squads myself in the past. When you first post a question there should be a "how to ask a good question" link displayed rather prominently, and it's a worthwhile read. Defending yourself is also a good thing: the downvote squads can appreciate some spunk OPs part. But, including the simple line "I've googled these phrases (...) but wasn't able to find any useful information" is a simple way to make it clear you've tried some legwork.

Comment: Just for clarification, are you referring to [Office 365 Video](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/explore-office-365-video) or [Video365](http://www.video365.com)?

Comment: Office 365 Video. I tagged the question with Office 365.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless the downvotes I will show you the results of my researches throughout the internet.

As stated in the DevNet regarding the Video REST API it seems not possible to query for users and their stats within the portal.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/video-rest-operations

This can surely change over the course of time.

Comment: One can hope. How MS has been going lately, I'd say your odds are better than they were before.